# What equipment do I need to hear my own voice feedback on phone calls?

Tags: microphone, voice

I was in a recording studio once with headphones/microphone and was able to hear my own voice through the headphones.  It was really nice as I was able to control my volume and enunciate much better than usual. What equipment would I need to be able to do this on regular phone calls with my iPhone?  Possible?

Comment: I think you could mod your apple brand headphone/mic combo with sort of mini amp connected to the microphone that sound would be split into the headphone. You would need basic soldering skills. I don't know enough to answer the question but that's what comes to mind.